# Anything slider does not display images

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

I'm trying to get the slider on the following page to display the freakin' images on the slider! http://www.ultimatebowhuntingtv.com/index.php/partners/ You can see in chrome developer tools under 'resources' that the images are being called from the correct location, so I just can't see why I can't see the images. I am using the AnythingSlider: http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/. And the code is below. Slider html below the

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Partners
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
</div>
</div>

<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="/js/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Anything Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/onplay/css/anythingslider.css">
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/onplay/js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>

    <!-- Define slider dimensions here -->
    <style>
    #slider { width: 700px; height: 390px; }
    </style>

    <!-- AnythingSlider initialization -->
    <script>
        // DOM Ready
        var J=jQuery.noConflict();
        J(function(){
            J('#slider').anythingSlider();
        });
    </script>

<div id="main">
    <div class="wrap-special">
        <div class="content full-width-special">
            <div class="post">
                <h1 class="title-special" style="display: none;"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <?php wp_reset_query(); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php edit_post_link( __('Edit', 'wpzoom'), ' ', ''); ?>

                <div class="entry " style="color: #fff;">
                    <img src="/images/bkg-title-partners.jpg" /><br />

                    <!--INSERT SLIDER HERE-->
                    <ul id="slider">

                        <li><img src="/images/slider/slider-1.jpg" alt=""/></li>

                        <li><img src="/images/slider/slider-2.jpg" alt=""/></li>

                        <li><img src="/images/slider/slider-3.jpg" alt=""/></li>

                        <li><img src="/images/slider/slider-4.jpg" alt=""/></li>

                    </ul>

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-scoutlook.jpg" alt="ScoutLook Weather" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">ScoutLook</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.scoutlookweather.com" title="ScoutLook Weather" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">Scoutlook is the most advanced weather resource available period!  You have instant access to precise weather details, solunar data, game feeding times, wind direction helping you with Scent Cone, Deer Logs and much more.  We rely on Scoutlook in our preparation and while we are in the field.</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-scoutlook-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[scoutlook]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-scoutlook-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-scoutlook-2.jpg" rel="lightbox[scoutlook]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-scoutlook-thumb-2.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-nufletch.jpg" alt="NuFletch Archery" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">NuFletch Archery</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://nufletch.org/wpNuFletch" title="NuFletch Archery" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text"></div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-nufletch-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[pse]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-nufletch-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-pse.jpg" alt="PSE Archery" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">PSE Archery</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://pse-archery.com" title="PSE Archery" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">We have used PSE Bows for the past five years and love them.  Why?...It is because they are the fastest bows on the market and have become some of the most accurate bows a bowhunter can shoot.  There are a lot of bows to choose from and we have shoot nearly all of them over the years.  We are shooting the new PSE Dream Season DNA bow this year and new Smoke Crossbow.  The DNA is the fastest, quietest, and most accurate bow I have put in my hands to date...</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-pse-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[nufletch]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-pse-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-muddy-bloodsport.jpg" alt="Muddy Bloodsport" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Muddy Bloodsport</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.gomuddy.com/About/Bloodsport.html" title="Muddy Bloodsport" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">Bloodsport arrows use Fly Straight Technology that allows them to be some of the most accurate arrows on the market.  Additionally, the Carbon technology used ensures that they are the most durable arrow on the market.  We have to know our arrow is going to be accurate and be durable so we can use them time and time again...</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-bloodsport-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[bloodsport]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-bloodsport-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-big-green-targets.jpg" alt="Big Green Targets" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Big Green Targets</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.biggreentargets.com" title="Big Green Targets" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">Big Green Targets are the only target we use when we practice in the backyard, range or when we arrive at our hunting destination.  They are made from 100% recycle material, heat bonded layered target and weather proof.  This leads to a durable target that will last for long time withstanding thousands of shots.  They have SUPER EASY Arrow Removal and are made here in the USA...</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-BGT-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[BGT]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-BGT-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-BGT-2.jpg" rel="lightbox[BGT]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-BGT-thumb-2.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-BGT-3.jpg" rel="lightbox[BGT]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-BGT-thumb-3.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-redneck-blinds.jpg" alt="Redneck Blinds" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Redneck Blinds</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.redneckblinds.com" title="Redneck Blinds" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">Redneck Blinds are a new addition to our hunting tools.  When you step into a Red Neck Blind you will see why they are becoming a market leader.  The 360 degree shooting ability, carpet floors, adjustable windows and generous room for several hunters or camera man.  We also love them because they help control our scent!</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-RNB-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[RNB]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-RNB-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-spypoint.jpg" alt="Spypoint Game Cameras" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Spypoint Game Cameras</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.spypoint.com" title="Spypoint Game Cameras" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">Spypoint is becoming the market leader when it comes to producing the most innovative game cameras on the market.  We rely on and use the LIVE 3G, Tiny W2 and new Tiny W3 wireless cameras to help us monitor our deer herd year round.  Spypoint also produces high quality security cameras such as the BF-8 with BLACK LED Technology.</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[spypoint]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-2.jpg" rel="lightbox[spypoint]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-thumb-2.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-3.jpg" rel="lightbox[spypoint]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-thumb-3.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-4.jpg" rel="lightbox[spypoint]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-thumb-4.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-5.jpg" rel="lightbox[spypoint]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-spypoint-thumb-5.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-swhacker.jpg" alt="Swhacker Broadhead" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Swhacker Broadheads</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.swhacker.com" title="Swhacker Broadhead" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">When it comes to broadheads Swhacker has become our broadhead of choice. We have 100% confidence in these broadheads for both our bows and crossbows. They Fly like a field point and have a huge cutting diameter. Broadside shots, angled shots or less than perfect shots the Swhacker gets the job done. I shot my Turkey Grand Slam with the Swhacker...</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-swhacker-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[swhacker]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-swhacker-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-yeti.jpg" alt="Yeti Coolers" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Yeti Coolers</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.yeticoolers.com" title="Yeti Coolers" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">We started using Yeti coolers this year as we Bowfish, Spearfish, and everyday use.  We love how durable they are and how well they keep our food and game cool.  Especially, on those long days on the water or traveling back from hunting trip.  We are using the Series 35 and 65 this year and love them!</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-yeti-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[yeti]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-yeti-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-always-lethal.jpg" alt="Under Armor Always Lethal" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Under Armor Always Lethal</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.underarmour.com" title="Under Armor Always Lethal" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">There is nothing worse than being too hot, too cold or uncomfortable in the woods.  Minimizing your movement is key to our success not matter if we are turkey hunting or bowhunting big game.  Under Armour clothing keeps us cool and comfortable in the Spring and Summer.  During the Fall and Winter we can stay in the woods longer because of the layering technology.  We are also using the new Scent Control Clothing along with HAW Rubber Boots that are extremely comfortable.</div>
                                <!--<div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-lethal-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[yeti]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-lethal-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-mossy-oak.jpg" alt="Mossy Oak" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Mossy Oak</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.mossyoak.com" title="Mossy Oak" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">Mossy Oak Infinity keeps us concealed during the fall no matter where we are bowhunting.  The level of depth, detail and definition is awesome with this pattern.  Our goal is the ensure we cover every base we can to put the advantage in our corner no matter if we are turkey hunting or bowhunting big game.  Mossy Oak Infinity in the fall gives us that edge..In the Spring we rely on Mossy Oak Obsession based on lighter colors and green elements incorporated into the pattern.</div>
                                <!--<div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-mossy-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[yeti]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-mossy-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div id="partner-box">
                        <div id="Pwrapper">
                            <img class="hover" src="/images/partners/partner-300x250-muddy.jpg" alt="Muddy" />
                            <div class="text">
                                <div class="partner-title">Muddy</div>
                                <div class="partner-website"><a href="http://www.gomuddy.com" title="Muddy" target="_blank">Visit their website</a></div>
                                <div class="partner-text">Muddy Tree Stands in our opinion are some of the most versatile stands on the market.  We love the adjustablity of their lock on stands that allow you to set up in a less than straight tree and still be comfortable for all day sit.  Additionally, we use their safeguard harness for ourselves and our boys who hunt with us.  I have 100% confidence in these safety harnesses to keep me and my children safe..</div>
                                <div class="partner-gTitle">Gallery <span style="color:#aeaeae; font-weight: normal;">- Click Image To Expand</span></div>
                                <div class="partner-gallery">
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[muddy]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-thumb-1.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-2.jpg" rel="lightbox[muddy]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-thumb-2.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-3.jpg" rel="lightbox[muddy]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-thumb-3.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-4.jpg" rel="lightbox[muddy]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-thumb-4.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-5.jpg" rel="lightbox[muddy]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-thumb-5.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <a href="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-7.jpg" rel="lightbox[muddy]"><img src="/images/partners/gallery-muddy-thumb-7.jpg" class="partner-gallery-thumb" /></a>
                                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--close partner box-->
                    <div style="clear: left;"></div>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>


                    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p class="pages"><strong>'.__('Pages', 'wpzoom').':</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- / .entry -->

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria', 'wpzoom');?>.</p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>          
            </div><!-- / .post -->

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- / #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Could you summarize the code part instead of pasting the whole page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#slider` container is set to `display:none` in your file style.css, at line 274.
Remove the display style or set it to `block` and your slider will show.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Can't believe I missed that!